# VBA Macro to sort and apply conditional formating to a range of cells with dynamic number of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, conditional-formatting

I have a range (the image below).

[image: screenshot of Excel]

Please note that:

- Range is generated by another application, so number of rows is ever changing, and is not formatted as an Excel 'table'
- The number of columns, however, is fixed.
- There is always a `Totals` row, which is always the last row (cells beyond this however contains formula evaluating to '')

I want help with a VBA Macro that will sort the range using header `D` as key (ascending):

[See link to the sorted table below]

Please note that:

- The `Totals` row (which is always the last row) should be ignored and not sorted.

After this sort, I want the same VBA Macro to apply conditional formatting to the range using the same header `D` as key - the formatting applies a border around the range where `D` is the same:

Final table is here: http://goo.gl/H118Lx

Please note that:

- I don't want border around unique values in header `D` i.e rows where the cell-value-count is not greater than 1.

Comment: What have you tried already? Why not go to the developer tab and record a macro, do it manually, and then put something together. We can help you if there are errors or it's not doing something as expected..

Comment: I have indeed tried to record a vba to sort but it doesnt ignore the total rows, also doesnt work for the conditional formating, I have researched but can't seem to make it work, help will be appreciated

Comment: you'll want to use vba to count all rows, subtract one, then sort that number of rows (excluding totals row). Then the [formatting](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/cells/Lesson4.htm) will need to be done after finding duplicates.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586429/vba-to-sort-table-and-ignore-total-row

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA at all. You just need a better understanding of the flexibility behind conditional formats. Because of that, I'm going to answer the question even though it's a poor one.

You can sort by column `D` as is and the totals row will be at the bottom if it's the only one with a blank in it. Apply your conditional formats to the entire column as shown below.

Format: Borders on the left
Range: `A:A`
Formula: `=AND($D1<>"",OR($D1=OFFSET($D1,-1,0),$D1=OFFSET($D1,1,0)))`

Format: Borders on the right
Range: `E:E`
Formula: `=AND($D1<>"",OR($D1=OFFSET($D1,-1,0),$D1=OFFSET($D1,1,0)))`

Format: Borders on the top
Range: `A:E`
Formula: `=AND($D1<>"",$D1<>OFFSET($D1,-1,0),$D1=OFFSET($D1,1,0))`

Format: Borders on the bottom
Range: `A:E`
Formula: `=AND($D1<>"",$D1=OFFSET($D1,-1,0),$D1<>OFFSET($D1,1,0))`

---

This method will turn this sheet:

[image: Before]

... into this sheet:

[image: After]